# Deletar subpasta de um Watcher finaliza o loop

Tags: java

O meu codigo é o seguinte:

```
try {
        watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        registerAll(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return;
    }

    while (true){
        WatchKey key;
        try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            return;
        }
        for (WatchEvent<?> event: key.pollEvents()) {
            WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();

            if (kind == OVERFLOW) {
                continue;
            }

            WatchEvent<Path> ev = (WatchEvent<Path>)event;
            Path filename = ev.context();
            Path dir = (Path)key.watchable();
            Path child = dir.resolve(filename);
            File file = child.toFile();

            System.out.println(kind + " | " + file);

            if(kind == ENTRY_CREATE && file.isDirectory()){
                register(file);//transforma file em path e registra
            }
        }

        boolean valid = key.reset();
        if (!valid) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

O problema é que quando uma subpasta e deletada, ele conta como overflow(quando uso debug o kind é overflow na hora) e o key.reset acaba sendo invalido, e o loop finaliza.

Comment: Você está registrando o watcher para os subdiretórios também?

Comment: sim, isso mesmo. registerAll faz isso, e esta funcionando ! o ruim e na hora que deleta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com os comentários, você está monitorando os subdiretórios recursivamente.

Porém, a [API do *WatcherService*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html) padrão suporta monitoramento de um diretório por vez, sendo que para monitorar vários diretórios você precisa fazer várias chamadas.

Logo, provavelmente você tem algum código que percorre a estrutura de diretórios adiciona o *watcher* recursivamente em cada subdiretório, como no [exemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java) abaixo:

```
private void registerAll(final Path start) throws IOException {
    // register directory and sub-directories
    Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException
        {
            register(dir);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
}
```

Se isso é verdade, significa que o seu loop está recebendo eventos de todos os diretórios.

Normalmente, o loop termina se o diretório for excluído, portanto é um comportamento esperado o que você descreve na pergunta.

Por outro lado, como você quer continuar monitorando os demais necessários, é necessário uma lógica adicional, isto é, um controle para somente sair do loop e executar o `break` no caso do diretório principal ser removido.

No [exemplo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java) que eu mencionei assim, isso é feito adicionando cada diretório monitorado a um mapa e então o loop é encerrado apenas quando se verifica que não há nenhum diretório sendo monitorado.

O trecho que faz isso no exemplo é este:

```
boolean valid = key.reset();
if (!valid) {
    keys.remove(key);

    // all directories are inaccessible
    if (keys.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
}
```